# caching a query that changes infrequently in Coldfusion/cfWheels

Tags: caching, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

I'm looking at the cache function in the [findAll](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/findall) function of cfWheels. I'm a little apprehensive about using it. My queries are not taking that long that I absolutely need them, but a bit of a speed boost is always welcome. I'm getting 10ms from a queried cache that otherwise takes about 100ms. The thing I'm wondering about is when an entry changes, I'd like the cache to be cleared on the next run. It doesn't seem like there's any mechanism or flag in the framework that would allow that, so I'd have to set and clear the flags myself, which would most likely end up having to read from the database anyway. I was hoping that I could set the cache for a full day and update when needed, is this horribly misguided? I'm most likely not going to go down the road of developing any of the functionality to allow the caching for this application, but am curious if it is worth while revisiting.

Comment: Whether it's worth re-visiting depends on how often the query gets run and how often the data gets updated.  You know that more than we do.

Answer (score 2):

Caching can be cleared through reloading an application. It would not be the answer you are seeking but is a solution, here is an another approach. You can reload an application through `<CFHTTP>` by sending URL through `<CFHTTP>` after adding your new database record. If you are adding record through management site, then you can reload your Public site using `<cfhttp>`.
  :)

Comment: I thought caching was a server thing, not an application thing.

Comment: @DanBracuk CfWheels as well as a plethora of other frameworks (afaik) allow caching at several levels (content, function, query). In the case of ColdFusion, the caching can be facilitated by the the server, but sometimes even the use of a flat file (xml/txt) backup can be faster than connecting to the database, especially if there are a lot of joins and records)

Comment: I'm finding that reloading the application can add extra time, if the changes are done too often, that might make things worse

Answer (score 2):

More precisely whenever you  make a new entry in the database,  use the cfhttp tag to reload the application.

Comment: This assumes the database write is done via the cf application which is not always the case.